# Using the same variables to print out receipt and thus the same values are being passed down for each item.

Tags: java

How can I change my code so this doesn't happen?

```
NumberFormat formatter = 
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    Candy item1 = new Candy(name, amount, price);
    Cookie      item2 = new Cookie( "Oatmeal Raisin 
Cookies", amount, price );
    IceCream    item3 = new IceCream( "Vanilla Ice 
Cream", amount, price, toppingPrice);
    System.out.println( item1 );
    System.out.println( item2 );
    System.out.println( item3 );
```

[How output should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8iwA.png)
[How my output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkEI7.png)

Comment: can you explain something other than `Using the same variables to print out receipt and thus the same values are being passed down for each item.`

Answer (score 0):

Any object passed to `System.out.println` will have its `toString()` method called.

Assuming that the three `System.out.println` calls in your sample code are expected to output the three lines like

`CANDY    [2]     Cost: $ 9.73  Tax : $0.68`

in your expected output, then you should focus your attention on the `toString()` methods of your `Candy`, `Cookie`, and `IceCream` classes.  Each of those methods should return the string as expected.

A simpler, more focused test case might be:

```
//setup  

Cookie myCookie = new Cookie("namevalue", 3, 10.50)  

//test  

assert myCookie.toString == "COOKIE    [3]     Cost: $ 10.50  Tax : $0.73"
```

If you are not familiar with assertions or test development, you can perform the assertion manually as you currently are as well, but even if not using the `assert` keyword, my recommendation would be to focus on a much smaller code example like the one in my sample test above.

Please note this test assumes a tax rate hard-coded at the same rate as in your sample output.